# Parsing JSON strings (Stringify)

Tags: ajax, json, coffeescript, stringify

I would like to just say thank you for anyone that helps. But I am not able to parse my AJAX response properly:

My AJAX Request:

```
$ ('#sumbit_LoggingGet').on 'click', ->
  username = $('#login_username').val()
  password = $('#login_password').val()
  mac_id = $('#login_LoggingGetmac').val()
  id = $('#login_LoggingGetid').val()

  $.ajax
    type: "GET"
    url: start_url + mac_id + "/log-config/" + id
    dataType: "json"
    crossDomain: true
    cache: false
    beforeSend: beforeSend(username, password)

    success: (data) ->
      console.dir data
      successMessage("""<h1>Logging Get Results</h1>""")
      clearColor(areaText = '#header_username')
      clearColor(areaText = '#header_password')
      clearColor(areaText = '#header_LoggingGetmac')
      clearColor(areaText = '#header_LoggingGetid')

      $('#data-results').html JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2)
      #(data, null, "\t", 2)
```

**My Current Results:**

{ "id": "logger1", "points": [ { "id": "00000000/pulse_1", "interval": 300000, "enabled": true } ], "reports": [ { "collector": "collector1@talkrnd.enernoc.net", "interval": 300000, "enabled": true } ], "capacity": 16070400000 }

**True Results:**

```
{
"id": "logger1",
"points": [
    {
        "id": "00000000/pulse_1",
        "interval": 300000,
        "enabled": true
    }
],
"reports": [
    {
        "collector": "collector1@talkrnd.enernoc.net",
        "interval": 300000,
        "enabled": true
    }
],
"capacity": 16070400000
}
```

**Wanted Output**

```
id: "logger1" 
points: "id": "00000000/pulse_1", "interval": 300000, "enabled": true 
reports: "collector": "collector1@talkrnd.enernoc.net", "interval": 300000, "enabled": true
capacity: 16070400000
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: what's the problem? you're getting normal looking results. You want us to write the code to produce your "wanted output"? If that's the case, then no. we're not here to do your job for you. YOU write some code to try and do that, then we'll try help fix it.

Comment: Thanks, but I did write the code already and even commented code that could be useful but the results come back in one long line. I was able to get a proper print out for my other 6 functions. So I am asking for help not code. To make it clear, just wanted to know what I am doing wrong with my stringify line...

Comment: And I have read documentation but nothing is working right. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON

Comment: All works.. But I am trying to parse correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In your true results (and current results), points is pointing to an array, whose entry or entries are maps `"id": "00000000/pulse_1", "interval": 300000, "enabled": true`.

In your "desired" output, `points` contains a single map, not in an array, which I believe to be not appropriate.. Points being plural implies you want many, possibly ordered items, as an array gives you.

So I would ask you why you are trying to force data into a mold that does not fit it, and if you really do want a single point, you can use `results.points = results.points[0]`